# How to use rm in an answer

Tags: discussion

Some answers on superuser, such as this one - https://superuser.com/a/1136881/7561 - include using the unix command of `sudo rm /something` - which could be extremely dangerous - as if a user didn't finish copying the command and just wrote `sudo rm /` and then clicked "enter" they will lose all of the data on their computer.

What is the best, safest way, to instruct people on how to use `rm` in a stack exchange answer?

Comment: See also: [Should potentially “Dangerous” answers be flagged/deleted?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1833/should-potentially-dangerous-answers-be-flagged-deleted), [Should every answer involving registry edits contain a warning to back up the registry?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/11793/should-every-answer-involving-registry-edits-contain-a-warning-to-back-up-the-re)

Comment: Actually, if you do `sudo rm /` in any modern Linux distro, it will not be as disastrous as you imagine.

Comment: But if you intend to say `sudo rm -rf ./*` (because `sudo` is so cool, y’know, that you use it whenever you’re not sure you don’t need it, and likewise for `./`) and you accidentally type `sudo rm -rf . /*`, that’s gonna leave a mark.

Answer (score 15):

That answer is a great example of how *to* do it - you're explaining what you're doing and what you're deleting step by step. We can't really completely stop people from [accidentally their own system](https://encyclopediadramatica.se/I_accidentally_X).

rm isn't *inherently* dangerous - many modern [rm implementations](https://serverfault.com/questions/587102/monday-morning-mistake-sudo-rm-rf-no-preserve-root) are designed to stop you from hoisting yourself on your own petard. I mean you *could* use [rm -i](https://superuser.com/questions/382407/best-practices-to-alias-the-rm-command-and-make-it-safer) in your answers or reference one of the [suggestions here](https://serverfault.com/questions/337082/how-do-i-prevent-accidental-rm-rf).

That said, if someone wants to break open the gun locker, grab a bullet from a locked drawer, load and fire a shot right into his own foot, there's precious little we can do.

Comment: "if someone wants to break open the gun locker" - a better analogy for telling non-technical users to use "sudo rm" is handing them a gun and telling them to use it, without having passed any weapons handling training to make sure they don't shoot themselves in the foot *by mistake*.

Comment: Oh, it quite literally is more difficult than that to rm -rf / - see my first link. You literally need to explicitly tell it to delete the root directory of a system

Comment: The guy in the third link you've attached wasn't saved by the safeguards :( although he also made use of an asterisk. In any case, the point was just that non-technical users don't *want* to do anything bad as your analogy suggests, just that they might do so by accident.

Comment: Btw, this is what [accidentally their own system](https://encyclopediadramatica.se/I_accidentally_X) means for those not accustomed to the meme.

Comment: Reminds me of a comment asking: [How do you even type `--no-preserve-root` accidentally?](http://serverfault.com/q/587102/214507#comment-690331)